# How to downgrade from default .NET Framework on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows-server-2019, .net, downgrade

I have a VM running Windows Server 2019 Standard. The O/S came out of the box with .NET Framework 4.8. I need to run some custom software that, according to the vendor, specifically requires 4.7.2. (I can verify that it's not working now, at least.) Since 4.8 was not the result of an upgrade or update, there is no installed update I can remove to downgrade. The Microsoft .NET doc says that it is not possible to uninstall the framework as of version 4. Other people say it is possible, but it breaks many of the essential O/S features and tools, making installing a different version extremely difficult. An hour of Google has turned up nothing more. Has anyone successfully gone from out-of-the-box 4.8 to 4.7.2 (or a similar path), and if so, would you please tell me how you did it?

Comment: I think it is easier to make the Software run under 4.8 than to downgrade the .NET Framework version to 4.72.

Comment: A vendor that is incapable of swiftly providing you a version of the software that works on an up-to-date system is probably also a vendor you no longer want to depend on anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Having run out of ideas completely I turned to the installed updates list and, out of the box or not, there were about a dozen listed. I looked them up individually and found that one of them, **KB4486153**, was a .NET upgrade. Removing that seems to have had the desired effect.